# How to handle the connection in MQTT using Paho

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, paho, publish-subscriber

I've managed to connect to my Mosquitto broker of Paho MQTT JS client. However, the client disconnects inmediately after completing the connection. Before it worked now I'm testing it doesn't work.

This is my code for the main functions involved:
constructor() {

```
    super();
    this.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost.bind(this)
    this.onConnect = this.onConnect.bind(this)
    this.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this)

    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(process.REACT_APP_HOST, Number(process.REACT_APP_PORT), clientID);
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.onConnect = this.onConnect;
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived

constuctor(){
    client.connect({

      onSuccess: this.onConnect,
      userName: process.REACT_APP_DB_NAME,
      password: process.REACT_APP_PASSWORD,
      onFailure: this.onConnectionLost,

    });
    this.state = {

      client,
      value: 0,
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.onConnect = this.onConnect.bind(this);

  }

  onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    console.log("Connected!!!!");

  }

  onConnectionLost = (responseObject) => {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost : " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }

  sendIntensity = () => {

    const { client } = this.state;

   client.publish(this.props.topic, this.state.value.toString(), 1)

  }
```

**console log:**

```
Connected!!!!
Connected!!!!
onConnectionLost : AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.
onConnectionLost : AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.
Connected!!!!
```

**Error :**

> Error: AMQJS0011E Invalid state not connected. at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox....

Comment: Are you trying to connect multiple times with the same client ID? Some brokers will drop a connection when a client ID is duplicated.

Comment: no i'm using random id : const clientID = "clientId-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10)

Comment: What do your mosquitto logs show? Also your console log is showing "Connected!!!" twice without any disconnect between them... is your code connecting twice before the disconnect?

Comment: Hence my question on whether you are somehow trying to connect multiple times with the same client ID. Perhaps you can log the clientID in OnConnect and OnConnectionLost events.

Comment: @romkey yeah it connect twice without disconnect every run I don't know why. Have you an idea ab it?

Comment: @kalyanswaroop yeah the problem was the client ID, I moved it to new Paho.MQTT.Client(process.REACT_APP_HOST, Number(process.REACT_APP_PORT),"clientId-" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10) ); without passing it in variable & that's work but why I have no idea !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(process.REACT_APP_HOST, Number(process.REACT_APP_PORT), clientID);
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived

constuctor(){
    client.connect({

      onSuccess: this.onConnect,
      userName: process.REACT_APP_DB_NAME,
      password: process.REACT_APP_PASSWORD,
      onFailure: this.onConnectionLost,

    });
```

You seem to define the handle to client.onConnect twice, which might account for connecting twice with the same client instance, hence the same client id and angry result.

Comment: So I shouldn't bind Connect func this.onConnect = this.onConnect.bind(this) ??

Comment: calling the onConnect() function more than once is redundantly redundant.

I amended the answer to be more clear as a solution vs. "remove this line"

The instantiation of the client object carries some event definitions onConnectionLost and onMessageArrived.  You have handled them already. 

I must also admit that I don't really follow the syntax as written in your example.  It may be my own ignorance showing.

Perhaps it would be a wise to add a lot of console.log("this is where I am"); statements so you can trace it in the browser JS console and see how it gets called more than once